# Google Maps API v3 DrawingManager : Change title attributes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drawing

I'm using `Google Maps API V3` and the `DrawingManager`.

When the mouse hovers my `DrawingManager`, the `title` attribute of the icons appears, but I'd like to change this title ("Dessiner une forme" here in French version) and put my own.

[image]

I try to use :

```
$("div.gmnoprint img[src$='drawing.png']").last().attr("title", "My custom title");
```

And this **works**, but :

- This solution seems ugly.
- It works in my browser's console, but I need an event `drawingmanager_complete` to run this code only when the manager is *fully loaded*, but according to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer) , it doesn't exist...

Is there any clean and reliable way to accomplish this ?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried building your own custom control?

Comment: No I didn't try, I didn't want to reinvent the wheel... I hoped a clean way exists, am I wrong ?

Comment: If there isn't a way to do it in the documentation (or the 3.exp version of the documentation), and I don't see one, then any way you do it will be a kludge and might change (unless you build your own custom control).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer geocodezip. As I guess you're close to Google, you should suggest this label problem for next versions of the API, I think a property like `labels` could be welcome and useful for a lot of people.

Comment: I have nothing to do with google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the API or the Library does not provide any end points that can be edited by the developer's to create there own custom once. The best way to do this is to just omit the pre-existing controls and then build your own.

One way to do this is by using this approach:

```
$(map.getDiv()).one('mouseover','img[src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/drawing.png"]',function(e){

    $(e.delegateTarget).find('img[src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/drawing.png"]').each(function(){
      $(this).closest('div[title]').attr('title',function(){
         switch(this.title){
          case 'Add a marker':
            return 'Add New Location';
              break;
          case 'Draw a circle':
            return 'Draw an area';
              break;
          default:return this.title;  
         } 

      });
    });
  });
```

And this will work with English as a language.  To achieve it regardless of the language you'll have to check the top-property of the button-image(this seems to be the only detail that may be used to determine the type of shape the button is used for).

Comment: This seems to work :-) However, 2 questions : How can I be 100% sure this code is executed once the drawingManager has been fully loaded ? It seems to be the case, but is there a way to be absolutely sure ?
And I don't understand what you mean by top property of button image ? I don't see anything related to language there...